# (Swift) How to find specific instance that's showed on debug console?

Tags: swift, ios13

I was making a quiz app on Xcode 11.3.1 and something went wrong. It says:

`2020-02-06 10:53:28.154874+0900 Quizzler-iOS13[6710:890558] -[Quizzler_iOS13.ViewController topButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa6180033d0`

I want to find out what is instance 0x7fa6180033d, but don't know how to locate this **0x7fa6180033d0**. How do I search for 0x7fa6180033d?

Comment: Note: I found out in Swift, generally "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error is related to: when same IBOutlet or IBAction is linked with buttons in Main.Storyboard more than one time. But still wondering if there is way to find certain instance showed on debug console.